# I use sb admin2, but i don't know that side bar is not working because of metis menu

Tags: jquery

my side bar is not working.

- No collpase
- No resize

because

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function sb-admin-2.js:3(anonymous function) sb-admin-2.js:3j jquery.js:3094k.fireWith jquery.js:3206n.extend.ready jquery.js:3412I jquery.js:3428
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):679(anonymous function) (index):679fire jquery.js:974self.fireWith jquery.js:1084jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:406DOMContentLoaded
```

I  think that In sb-admin-2.js,

```
$(function() {

    $('#side-menu').metisMenu();

});
```

is not working and Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I hope... I will be helped...

Comment: I also used metis menu. And this is the exact problem I got. Can anybody help us?

Comment: i think that it's jquery problem. When I modify jquery reference, it's working! I recommend that you should review jquery sentence(ex : <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/assets/js/plugins/cube/jquery.js")"></script>)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have loaded jquery first, then sb-admin-2.js.
Also make sure you only load them once.

I had the same problem and found that I had accidentally loaded both jquery and sb-admin-2.js twice, once directly with a  tag and once as part of a bundle of multiple javascript files. I think loading jquery twice was the culprit in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Call Metis after the view is initialised and also Make sure you have the ordered your JS libraries in correct order. For me the sequence is as follows:

```
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/plugins/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/global/plugins/select2/js/select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```